# Limitations of real mode as it pertains to device driver development

Tags: x86, device-driver, osdev, real-mode

My query is regarding device driver development.

If I wish to use real mode to make a Toy OS, but decide to write a network stack/set of network drivers, is there enough room to do so? Will I need to do like DOS and swap to Protected Mode to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Protected mode is not a requirement for implementing networking - DOS had it before PM was offered by CPUs.

Comment: noted, but what card these days will configure without accessing PCI (32bit)? Perhaps an old RTL chipset? That's basically what I was asking if PMode was a requirement. so it seems I must find a card that will play nice.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing DNS, IP, TCP, UDP, ICMP, IGMP, ARP, MAC, etc. in real mode is possible, but some Network Card Drivers are quite big!

If you want to use BIOS interrupt routines I recommend switching to [HUGE UNREAL MODE](http://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode#Huge_Unreal_Mode) which allows you to access more memory, or use [VIRTUAL 8086 MODE](http://wiki.osdev.org/Virtual_8086_Mode) allowing you to create something like a 16-bit real mode virtual machine in 32-bit protected mode, so you can use all the benefits of PM and access BIOS Routines from it. That is assuming you don't mind switch to Protected Mode.